# Is it possible to create a 'splash' screen using the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have built a custom Google Map and When the page loads I would like a 'splash screen' to appear over the map inside the map container (this would be an image with some instructions), which could then either be toggled off or would disappear after a set time.

I know that I can do this using CSS/JQuery to create a layer over the map container, but is it possible to do this using the map API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use overlays or a custom infowindow (infobox).
I would suggest overlays. Their existence is for displaying components
over the map. Infowindow would suffice too, but their role is for displaying something
in relation to a specific spot on the map.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple) for more

Comment: Thanks... so load the image as a layer that loads with the map and fixed to a point that will be visible within the initial map view?  Is it possible to add a duration (time) that the image/layer will appear before toggling off or can this only be achieved manually within the API?

Comment: Yeap, that's the idea. With the use of setTimeout or the like, you will remove/hide it when you are done. I don't think that there is something for the duration. You will have to do it manually.